# Suggestions on how to access google webmaster tools' api through R?

Tags: r, curl, google-api, google-search-console

I wish to access my Google Webmaster's tools' API via R.

I see from here:

http://code.google.com/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/reference.html

That it requires fetching a feed behind https and parsing it.

Any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Perhaps you can adapt this code from sorenmacbeth http://github.com/sorenmacbeth/googleanalytics4r/blob/master/R/googleanalytics4r.R

Comment: Thanks Brandon, that was my fallback plan - I was wondering if someone else had already touched the topic.

Answer (score 2):

Based on some Googling, I'd say the RCurl library is your best bet for the HTTP stuff. They have a good example on how to do some basic operations and work with an XML payload: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/xmlParse.html

Like other GData services, the webmaster tools api is AtomPub-based XML. It should be fairly easy to parse using the XML library, but you'll need to code that yourself.

Googleanalytics4r mentioned by Brandon takes this same approach. See: https://github.com/sorenmacbeth/googleanalytics4r/blob/master/R/googleanalytics4r.R

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the [Java client](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) with [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/).

Comment: Hi Matti, could you be a bit more specific - I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: For the java side of things there are some examples http://code.google.com/intl/fi-FI/apis/webmastertools/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java.html, as how to call it from rJava I think you need to refer to its documentation. I'm not a Java programmer myself, but there a lot of projects that use rJava succesfully.

Comment: RGoogleData source might also give you some tips r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rgoogledata/

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit hacky, but I access GWT data from R through the python tool here (http://code.google.com/p/webmaster-tools-downloads/source/browse/downloader.py), by issuing system() commands e.g.

```
feedback <- system("python ./gwt-tool/googlewebmastertool_download_gmt.py")
```

Where "feedback" will be the message's generated from the script, and the files appear in the working directory of the system call.

A better solution would be to use httr package to make the requests (which is a wrapper for RCurl suggested above) - I've found that httr smooths out some of the problems of configuration that RCurl can present.